# AWS Glue add new partitions and overwrite existing partitions

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm attempting to write pyspark code in Glue that lets me update the Glue Catalog by adding new partitions and overwrite existing partitions in the same call.

I read that there is no way to overwrite partitions in Glue so we must use pyspark code similar to this:

```
final_df.withColumn('year', date_format('date', 'yyyy'))\
            .withColumn('month', date_format('date', 'MM'))\
            .withColumn('day', date_format('date', 'dd'))\
            .write.mode('overwrite')\
            .format('parquet')\
            .partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day')\
            .save('s3://my_bucket/')
```

However with this method, the Glue Catalog does not get updated automatically so an `msck repair table` call is needed after each write. Recently AWS released a new feature `enableUpdateCatalog`, where newly created partitions are immediately updated in the Glue Catalog. The code looks like this:

```
additionalOptions = {"enableUpdateCatalog": True}
additionalOptions["partitionKeys"] = ["year", "month", "day"]
dyn_frame_catalog = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(
            frame=partition_dyf,
            database = "my_db",
            table_name = "my_table",
            format="parquet",
            additional_options=additionalOptions,
            transformation_ctx = "my_ctx"
)
```

Is there a way to combine these 2 commands or will I need to use the pyspark method with `write.mode('overwrite')` and run an `MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_table` on every run of the Glue job?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already found your answer, I believe the following will work:

```
DataSink5 = glueContext.getSink(
    path = "s3://...", 
    connection_type = "s3", 
    updateBehavior = "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE", 
    partitionKeys = ["year", "month", "day"], 
    enableUpdateCatalog = True, 
    transformation_ctx = "DataSink5")

DataSink5.setCatalogInfo(
    catalogDatabase = "my_db",
    catalogTableName = "my_table")

DataSink5.setFormat("glueparquet")
DataSink5.writeFrame(partition_dyf)
```

Comment: Is it the `updateBehavior` that enables the partitions to be updated in S3? I am still getting duplicated files within the partitions.

Comment: If you are re-running your jobs, and not cleaning out S3, then you will end up with duplicates. You could also get duplicates if you are not creating your bucket prefixes correctly.  The “partitionKeys” defines the partitions. The “updateBehavior” is more about how the data catalog is updated.